# excludeFromRecents in Android 6 and 7

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-7.0-nougat

**First I should say that this is a problem from Android 6.0 and above.**

I have one application that I exclude from recent application list in Android with:

```
 android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

But in the new version of Android this also works but if I press the button **close all** or **end all** application, my application is closed and in previous Android version this does not happen.

It is possible to handle this situation in new Android version to keep the same behavior?

The button is the one in the bottom right corner is this picture:

[image]

Comment: What "button close all or end all" are you referring to? Beyond that, since your process can be terminated at any point, for any reason, by the user or the OS, why does the fact that your process is terminated concern you?

Comment: The button is the one in the picture (look to the question again) in the bottom right conner. Concern me because I need that the application does not loose information important that is in the Service.

Comment: That entire screen is not part of standard Android. You will need to ask your device manufacturer or custom ROM developer what that actually does, with respect to the Android SDK. "I need that the application does not loose information important that is in the Service" -- then you should be saving the data when the data changes to some persistent storage. Again, Android and the user can terminate your process, without warning, at any point. Data held in memory is purely a cache, nothing more.

Comment: yes I know that is not a Standart but the same happen when you press in the Nexus... The button in the normal close all aplication... With same behaviour.

Comment: But I need to mantain the information only in RAM :(

Comment: "But I need to mantain the information only in RAM" -- then you will need to switch to a mobile OS that you control, so you can control your process lifetime. That could be a custom Android ROM (e.g., where your app is converted into a standard Linux daemon process), or embedded Linux, or something.

Comment: But to mitigate this is possible? In the previous version, I'm capable of doing that...

Comment: "In the previous version, I'm capable of doing that" -- only in this one limited case. You are not capable of preventing the user from pressing Force Stop on your app in Settings. You are not capable of preventing the user from using a task killer, which may have similar impacts to what you are seeing here. You are not capable of preventing Android from terminating your process due to an urgent need for system RAM. In those cases, once your process terminates, your "information only in RAM" is gone. "But to mitigate this is possible?" -- for this limited case, I have no idea.

Comment: ok, thanks for the reply, but all the other options are important and are decision from the user and I care. This options that I want to mitigate is only  a problem in new version, and are based on the fact that the user can easly do that.